# Does CoreData automatically implement memory warnings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-data

[CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001200-SW1), among other things, is designed to keep an application memory footprint low.

However I could not find any information on weather or not it implements the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` notification.

I assume it drops its cache as this would be the sensible thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data does something conceptually similar called faulting which limits how many object in the graph are in memory at any given time. I'd read up on it here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html

Comment: This is a great resource. I found that I can use `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` to re-fault an individual object.  However this does not answer the question:  Does core data do this by default in low memory situations?

Comment: Yes Core Data does this by default on OS X & iOS. There are some things specific to iOS with how you can work with Core Data to retrieve specific attributes on entities and get notified of changes through NSFetchedResultsController https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html but it still mostly works the same